# AndroidViewClient get id's from WebView

Tags: android, python-2.7, android-4.3-jelly-bean, androidviewclient

I have Samsung Android 4.3 API 18 and using AndroidViewClient, the dump produces only android.webkit.WebView therefore it's not possible to get all the id's within this page.
How Can I use Culebra to record the actions in the web page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Features#hover-hierarchy) shows how the elements inside the WebView are listed.

To do it you have to use **AndroidViewClient** with [culebra](http://culebra.dtmilano.com) backend, as the dump produced by uiautomator does not include them.

Comment: Yes I use Culebra to generate actions with the coordinates inside the webview, thanks.